# force fields only affect non-dynamic hair

Tags: animation, particles, force-fields

I try to use the hair system to do grass and like to animate it with a vortex.
When hair dynamics is'nt active, the force fields actually affect the hair/grass but its not animated.

But when I activate the dynamics, it stop being affected by anything, and its not even moving with the gravity.

I read some tutorial and docs and I can't see what I'm missing.

I don't know if this is important but I'm using the bahiagrass pack from blender guru.
I tried to move about anything in the hair parameters without succes
I can provide screenshot if needed but since I don't really know what could be important here.

Comment: have you baked the hair's dynamics? press ctrl+a and see if the hair start being affected by the vortex

Comment: I tried ctrl+a and also bake from the cache section but it doesn't do anything more

Comment: can you upload some screenshots of the settings of the particle system? and maybe the vertex settings too.

Comment: here the particle settings, sorry for the raw screenshot, I'm mouseless and painfully do thing with trackpad >>.  http://imgur.com/a/HIeQe . the circles you see on the scene is the wind force field (I was testing with wind right now)

Comment: Well. I started over and it work very well now (except that the vortex is'nt acting like I thought it was and the failoff is not really working (at least like I wanted) But I'll ask another question for that.  Since I don't have an answer I don't really know what to do for this one: Vote for delete ? post an answer saying to do it again (I don't think that a good idea) ?